# Objective C: (NSSet *)annotationsInMapRect:(MKMapRect) mapRect method returns null value

Tags: objective-c, ios, annotations, mapkit

I am trying to implement the following method in my application

```
NSSet *nearbySet = [self.mapView annotationsInMapRect:self.mapView.visibleMapRect];
```

I see in my mapView there are 4 annotations, however, the method returns me 0 values in the set.

Can anyone advise if I have missed out on anything here?

Thanks in advance.

Zhen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three quick things to check as a "sanity check":

1. What is the value of self.mapView? Make sure it isn't nil.
2. What does self.mapView.annotations contain?
3. What is the value of self.mapView.visibleMapRect?

Comment: thanks for the tip! I found my error, it seems that I have added the statement at the wrong place in my code. It's working now. Thanks a lot!